# Why is Servlet page refreshing/reloading instead of redirecting (using meta tag)?

Tags: servlets, cookies

```
*//post method*
protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException,IOException {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password"); 
        System.out.println( " Form data recieved .. Now Verifying ");

        if ( loginVerificator ( username, password ) )  {
            Cookie xO = new Cookie ( "username", username );
            Cookie xT = new Cookie ( "password", password );            
            res.addCookie( xO );
            res.addCookie( xT );
            res.setContentType( "text/html" );
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter( );
            out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2\";url=\"home\">");
        }
```

The post method retrieves the form parameters and then creates cookies from them and adds those cookies to the response. Then it redirects the page with meta tag.

I want to know why this page is reloading instead of redirecting. I am not able to find where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2\";url=\"home\">");`

writes a `meta` tag in the response with the following value:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2";url="home">` which is incorrect, as the url is not wrapped by the quotes for the content attribute value. Instead the tag should have been generated as:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=home">` which requires the corresponding line in the servlet to be:

`out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;url=home\">");`

---

Note that the `meta refresh` concept has been [deprecated by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element). If you intend to redirect the user to a new page, it is always preferable to use a HTTP 302 response, which is easily doable in Servlets using the [`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(location)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) method.